# Proving there is no polynomial algorithm for independent set

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np, approximation

I need some guidance in an assignment I'm doing.

I'm at complete loss, he says the the MAXIMUM INDEPENDENT SET problem is NP-hard and then asks me to prove that there is no polynomial time for the same algorithm and it also guarantees that some inequality holds, which I also don't understand, since $A(G)$ returns the size of a maximal independent set in $G$ and $OBT(G)$ returns the size of an independent set of maximal size for $G$ but isn't the case that a graph could have multiple maximal independent sets? Let's assume that it returns the largest one which reduces the epression to $0 \le K$ which should always holds since $K$ is a natural number?

As for the hint given, I don't see how we can use $H$ if I understand it correctly, it says split $G$ into disjoint sets. Also it says for every instance $G$ which is confusing me.

When I asked the professor she was very reluctant to help me, so please any guidance is appreciated.

The full question:  [image: here] .

Comment: The question is badly worded -- it first mentions "Maximum Independent Set", and then defines it in terms of the size of a *maximal* independent set, when these are (perhaps surprisingly) very different: A maxim*al* independent set is just one that can't have any further vertices added to it and still remain an independent set; such a set can easily be found in quadratic (probably even linear) time.  Also it uses the word "solved" in a non-standard way: "solve" always means "find an optimal solution", but here (I infer that) they sometimes use it to mean "find an approximate solution".

Comment: The hint in that question is good, though.  I think your problem is that you are trying to think about a specific G, and perhaps a specific algorithm that does something with it -- that won't help you solve this problem, because you have to show something that works for *any* graph G.

Comment: Start by assuming to the contrary that there exists a poly-time algorithm that can find the K-approximate solution to *any* graph G, and then show that there is something you can do to *any* graph G to make some new graph G' from it that can be given as input to this approximation algorithm, which will result in that algorithm's output "leaking" the true size of the original G's maximum I S.  This would mean that you have solved Max I S in poly-time, which contradicts the P!=NP assumption.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Now I think you made it much clearer, but the only sensible way I can think of is to cut the graph to a disjoint union but won't that affect the independent set of the original graph? Or is the union of the independent sets from the chopped graph would be the same as the original graph?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Also if we can assume there exists a poly-time algorithm that can find an approximate of the independent set size, why don't we assume instead an algorithm that approximates, an algorithm that actually finds the exact size?

Comment: @j_random_hacker in your example what is the purpose of cutting the graph into smaller ones, is it a limit to our poly-time algorithm? Then can't we just say that "assume we have a poly-time algorithm that finds the size of the independent set, this means I solved Max IS in poly-time which contradicts the P != NP assumption. Therefore there is no polynomial time algorithm" which concludes the proof?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cutting", but I don't think that will be helpful.  (Do you mean cutting some edges?  What if G contains no edges?)  The hint already tells you a good operation to use ;)

Comment: "Also if we can assume there exists ... why don't we assume instead ..." -- you can't just assume the thing you want to prove.  One thing you *can* do is assume that the statement to be proven is *false*, and then derive a contradiction -- this is what we are doing by assuming that there *does* exist a poly-time approximation algorithm.  We later show this leads to a contradiction, meaning there must not exist a poly-time approximation algorithm.

Comment: I have one more hint for you: Suppose you find a magic box that can answer questions about the future.  You can ask it any number of questions, and it will tell you the answers -- but up to 5 answers could be wrong, and you don't know which ones.  You have one specific question that you really want the correct answer to -- is it possible to ask the box some questions in such a way that you can be sure you get a correct answer to this question?  A key point is that you may ask the same question multiple times...

Comment: @Zed, can you add tag "approximation" to your question? Also, since j_random_hacker has pointed out, could you make it clear _in the question_ that $A$ is just an approximation algorithm and remove the argument about $K\ge 0$? Otherwise, every reader will have to figure out that misleading statement. (This is about my last comment here since you are in good hands.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker so the hint says make a new graph H which has multiple copies of G (e.g. H contains G_1 and G_2 which are copies of G). Then if we feed H to our magic box it will return the size of the IS in H which is the size of the IS in G divided by the number of copies of G in H. We do this an arbitrary number of times until the IS size converges to a number which should be the correct IS size. However, this means we solved it in poly-time which contradicts P!=NP thus our statement is false. Does this sound right?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Also I don't see how would we use the expression $|A(G)-OPT(G)| <= K$ in anyway

Comment: "which is the size of the IS in G divided by the number of copies of G in H" -- is it really *divided*?

Comment: @j_random_hacker it returns the the maximum size of an IS and if we have two disjoint copies of G then it will return the greater size of the two copies which should be different but close to each other since we use an approximation algorithm, yeah this makes sense now. But then why do we need to build a new graph if we can just keep asking the magic box about the size of IS of G, is it because it will return the same answer again and again without converging to its true size?

Comment: "it will return the greater size of the two copies" -- will it really?  Try making 2 copies of a small example graph G.

Comment: @j_random_hacker well if we have a K-approximate solution which means we won't get the exact size but close to it, thats why some runs of this algorithm might result in different answers since its just an approximation. Now if we construct graph H which has two copies of G and run our algorithm to this new graph H the size of the IS of both copies of G should be the same because we are not in a different run. So to get the true size of the IS of G we run the algorithm on G, H (two copies of G), H' (three copies of G) ... and the true size would be the average of all those runs, is this sound?

Comment: Suppose G is a single edge $ab$.  What is the true size of the largest IS in G?  Now let H be two disjoint copies of G, i.e., 2 edges, $ab$ and $cd$.  What is the true size of the largest IS in H?

Comment: @j_random_hacker the true size of the largest IS in G is 1 {a} or {b}, the true size of the largest IS in H is 2 {a,c} or {a,d} or {b,c} or {b,d}. so the true size of IS in H is the true size of IS in G _times_ how many copies of G in H.

Comment: Now you are getting somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there exists an integer $K$ and a polynomial time algorithm $A$ which, when run on a graph $G$, outputs a value $A(G)$ which satisfies
$$
 |A(G) - \alpha(G)| \leq K,
$$
where $\alpha(G)$ is the maximum size of an independent set in $G$.

We will show that $A$ can be used to determine $\alpha(G)$ in polynomial time, which contradicts the assumption $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$.

Given a graph $G$, let $H$ consist of $2K+1$ disjoint copies of $G$; note that $\alpha(H) = (2K+1) \alpha(G)$. Run $A$ on $H$ to get a value $A(H)$ which satisfies
$$
 |A(H) - \alpha(H)| \leq K \Longrightarrow |A(H) - (2K+1) \alpha(G)| \leq K \Longrightarrow \\
 (2K+1)\alpha(G) \in \{A(H)-K,\ldots,A(H)+K\}.
$$
The set on the right contains $2K+1$ values, exactly one of which is a multiple of $2K+1$, hence we can determine $\alpha(G)$ given $A(H)$.